# change white space with regular expression in python

Tags: python, text, split

I need to change white space to a character, but only if there are two or more white spaces and there is only one I want to keep it.

An example of text is:
`142526     0x8520003  2     2022-10-20 The interface status changes. (ifName=Gig.`

I need:
`142526;0x8520003;2;2022-10-20 The interface status changes. (ifName=Gig.`

I use:

```
';'.join(headers.split())
```

but change one space white also. Thanks!!

Comment: Are those TAB characters between the fields?

Comment: Have you tried with [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.split()` to match more than one space.

```
import re

new_headers = ';'.join(re.split(r'\s{2,}', headers))
```

`\s` matches whitespace, and `{2,}` means to match 2 or more of them in a row.

Comment: Thanks! Barmar, ';'.join(re.split(r'\s{2,}', headers))

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `maxsplit=` parameter in `str.split`:

```py
s = """142526     0x8520003  2     2022-10-20 The interface status changes. (ifName=Gig."""

s = ";".join(s.split(maxsplit=3))
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
142526;0x8520003;2;2022-10-20 The interface status changes. (ifName=Gig.
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be done using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), see [this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##TYw9C8JAEET7@xXLVRFi2GyMCJLazspOLc64yV2RD/YuoIi//Yyi4BQD8xjeeA926IsYXTcOEkBYKcvmyuKhAp2vqKQ1vIO3TUmIWADQBxASLXNcEsLBMrg@sDSmZvDBhMlDbU3fss8gcc3edFztXJvpP7tw5qdLIvoIp3B@UPrUKejtXN/PQqlRZm/y2zG@AA).

```
headers = re.sub(r"[ \t]{2,}", ";", headers)
```

The pattern will match [two or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) horizontal spaces.

Comment: That looks easier :-)